# typescript argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type Value[][]

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I'm trying to create stacked Bar chart using D3js in typescript. Below is my code snipptet.

```
let testData = [
  {
    month: "Jan",
    A: 20,
    B: 5,
    C: 10
  },
  {
    month: "Feb",
    A: 30,
    B: 10,
    C: 20
  }
];

var xData = ["A", "B", "C"];
var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function(c) {
  return testData.map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: d.month,
      y: d[c]
    };
  });
});
var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);
```

When I tried to pass dataIntermediate to stack I'm getting below error.
    **

> Argument of type '{ x: string; y: any; }[][]' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'Value[][]'

**.

I'm new to typescript, not able to understand what I'm doing mistake here.

Comment: Don't know much about TypeScript, but [this](https://hstefanski.wordpress.com/2017/08/15/creating-a-chart-with-d3-v4-and-typescript-or-es6/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because the Value interface is expecting both x and y to be numbers, but x is a string.

You will have to replace your month tags by numbers for it to work, as such:

```
let testData = [
  {
    month: 0,
    A: 20,
    B: 5,
    C: 10
  },
  {
    month: 1,
    A: 30,
    B: 10,
    C: 20
  }
];
```

If you can't change your data, you can also use the index of your samples:

```
var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function(c) {
  return testData.map(function(d, i) {
    return {
      x: i,
      y: d[c]
    };
  });
});
```